# Moodle, guest and frontpage

Tags: moodle, restriction, frontpage

I've exhausted my search on moodles site and the web-at-large.

I have a need to grant an individual (not a registered/regular user) temporary access to take a course/quiz, capture results and archive actions.

I want to manually enter said user into moodle and assign them a "guest" role so that I can then enrol them into a course and accomplish said goal.

The problem is, when I exercise this, the "guest" can view categories, courses and some other items within the site.  I do not want the guest to be able to see ANYTHING but the assigned course (and their grade)...I want to "lock-it-down".

I have been through every permission to the extent of "Prohibiting" everything, however, the guest role is still able to select some items and "peak" into other categories/courses.

Moreover, I don't want them to see the same menu items either...such as Dashboard

If you can point me in the right direction or solve this problem, I will be forever grateful.

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Manually entering said user will make her registered whatsoever, nevermind assigning her a guest role, which is, as I understand, heavily modified by you at this point (best practice here is to create your own copies of role instead of modifying existing ones).

The solution will require code modifications, since role capabilities are not covering everything. However, you may prohibit user to peek into any course(not category) by prohibiting self-enrolments, if it suits your strategy.